# TypedDataSetGenerator ignoring HierarchicalUpdate option?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation

I'm using `System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator` to convert a `.xsd` file (generated by VS2008) into a strongly-typed `DataSet` class compatible with .NET 2.0. From what I understand from MSDN, the [`HierarchicalUpdate` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.design.typeddatasetgenerator.generateoption.aspx) must be specified to get the same result that the VS2008 IDE generates:

**HierarchicalUpdate** - Generates typed datasets that have a TableAdapterManager and associated methods for enabling hierarchical update.

So I've specified that option, as you can see in the code below, but the outputted `.Designer.cs` file contains no `TableAdapterManager`... it doesn't even have any `TableAdapters`! Does VS2008 have its own internal Typed DataSet generator that it uses, or am I missing something, or is this a .NET bug?

```
  string schemaContent;

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\CVS\CallRetrieverPlain\CallRetrieverPlain\CallRecordingsDataSet.xsd"))
  {
    schemaContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }

  string output = string.Empty;

  using (CSharpCodeProvider cscp = new CSharpCodeProvider())
  {
    CodeCompileUnit ccu = new CodeCompileUnit();
    CodeNamespace cn = new CodeNamespace("DataSet.Generation.Test");

    output = TypedDataSetGenerator.Generate(schemaContent, ccu, cn, cscp,
                                            TypedDataSetGenerator.GenerateOption.HierarchicalUpdate);

    using (StringWriter codeWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
      // *** this line causes full generation as expected ***
      cscp.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(cn, codeWriter, null);
      cscp.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(ccu, codeWriter, null);

      output = codeWriter.ToString();
    }
  }

  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test-tmp\CallRecordingsDataSet.Designer.cs"))
  {
    writer.Write(output);
  }
```

**EDIT**: played around a bit more and found I have to add a call to `CodeDomProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace()` as well as `CodeDomProvider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit()` (commented in the above code). It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself, see the comments in the question.